# Laravel Image Upload Issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to upload an image using `Laravel` it is working to the point that the images are being successfully placed into the destination folder but when I try to view them within my `IDE` I am told they are corrupt and that `netbeans` cannot open them.

I am wondering if my `upload` process is causing this?

This is my code:

```
public function handleCreate(){
        $book = new Book;
        $book->title = Input::get('title');
        $book->desc = Input::get('desc');

        //Img uploading...
        $destinationPath = '';
        $filename = '';
        if(Input::hasFile('cover')){
            $file = Input::file('cover');
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/img/';
            $filename = str_random(6) . "_" . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $uploadSuccess = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        }

        $book->cover = $filename;

        $book->save();
        return Redirect::route('books')->with('msg', 'test');
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated. I know the image is not corrupt before uploading as I can view on my desktop. The issue is only after uploading it.

Comment: What about a plain text file, or other text and binary files? You should be able to see quite easily if a text file is being corrupted, and you may be able to determine the way it's being corrupted. Also check the file sizes, it may be being truncated for some reason. Obviously none of this solves the issue, but can help you work out what's going on exactly.

Comment: I've just done this, it seems to be a permission issue on my machine, Basically I can run paint as an administrator and open the image but I cannot directly open it in paint.

Comment: Ahh yeah that can happen with certain configurations. You PHP process is probably set to be very restrictive on permissions it creates files with (maybe 600). You may be able to fix the default permissions it by changing PHP process's umask to 0. See the [umask docs](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php). If that doesn't work (I may be wrong about how umask works - I think it's a way of limiting a process to a 'maximum permission openness', if you get what I mean), you may have to do a hacky [chmod](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) to 644 on files.